# Marketing Cloud - Replacing Multiple hardcoded values in JOINS with values from Parameter Table

Tags: marketing-cloud, sqlserver, sql

Salesforce Marketing Cloud query activities do not allow variables or temporary tables according to the "SQL Support" section of this official documentation (http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)

I have a data extension called Parameters_DE with fields Name and Value that stores constant values. I need to refer to this DE in queries.

For example, the query below has numerous hard-coded values that I would store in Parameters_DE

```
SELECT
Food,
Menu.Price,
Desserts.Name,
Vendor.Supplier
FROM
Food_DE
JOIN
Menu_DE as Menu
ON
Menu.Price > 20
JOIN
Desserts_DE AS Desserts
ON
Name = 'Cake'
JOIN
Vendor_DE as Vendor
ON
Supplier = 'McDonalds'
WHERE
(
Menu.Rating > 3
AND
Desserts.Sugar_Content < 50
AND
Supplier.Certified = 'True'
)
```

Is there any way to replace the multiple hard-coded values such as 20, 'Cake', 'McDonalds', 3, 50 and 'True' by referring to Parameters_DE using JOINs or other means given the limitations that SF Marketing Cloud does not support variables or temporary tables in query activities? I know it is certainly possible if there was only one hard-coded value but I am not sure how to make it work with multiple.

Comment: Hi CodeMonkey, is the goal of this query to produce a Result Table that contains only Menu items that exist in "Food_DE" which match the criteria specified in "Parameters_DE"? If so, how often will Parameters_DE be updated. Are you likely to add/remove parameters, or will they _always_ be "Rating, Price, Supplier, etc.."?

Answer (score 0):

You can always join to a parameter data extension:

```
SELECT
Food
, Menu.Price
, Desserts.Name
, Vendor.Supplier
FROM Food_DE
inner join Parameters_DE as p on queryname = 'food1'
JOIN Menu_DE as Menu ON Menu.Price > p.price
JOIN Desserts_DE AS Desserts ON Name = p.dessertName
JOIN Vendor_DE as Vendor ON Supplier = p.supplier
WHERE (
    Menu.Rating > 3
    AND Desserts.Sugar_Content < 50
    AND Supplier.Certified = 'True'
)
```

Updating the Parameters_DE can be done with another query:

```
select 
'20' as price
, 'cake' as dessertName
, 'McDonalds' as supplier
, 'food1' as queryname
/* name: Parameters_DE_Update */
/* target: Parameters_DE */
/* action: update */
```